# implementing model binder to bind a certain data format

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to model bind this this data that is sent from the client

```
tag[15-d] : Little Owl
tag[19-a] : Merlin

name : value
```

into `IEnumrable<AutoCompleteItem>`

```
public class AutoCompleteItem
{
  public string Key { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

for example

```
Key = 15-d
Value = Little Owl
```

i don't know how to implement my own model binder in this scenario , any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a model binder that I did for you and does what you want. It by no means complete (no validation, no error checking etc), but it can kick start you. One thing I particularly dislike is that the ModelBinder directly accesses the form collection instead of using the ValueProvider of the context, but the latter doesn't let you get all bindable values.

```
public class AutoCompleteItemModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    // Normally we would use bindingContext.ValueProvider here, but it doesn't let us
    // do pattern matching.
    public object BindModel (ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string pattern =  @"tag\[(?<Key>.*)\]";
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (bindingContext.ModelName))
            pattern = bindingContext.ModelName + "." + pattern;

        IEnumerable<string> matchedInputNames = 
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(inputName => Regex.IsMatch(inputName, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));

        return matchedInputNames.Select (inputName =>
            new AutoCompleteItem {
                Value = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[inputName],
                Key = Regex.Match(inputName, pattern).Groups["Key"].Value
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Here is a sample action that uses it:

```
[HttpPost]
public void TestModelBinder ([ModelBinder(typeof(AutoCompleteItemModelBinder))]
                             IList<AutoCompleteItem> items)
{
}
```

And a sample view. Note the "items." prefix - it's the Model Name (you can drop it depending on how you submit this list of items:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm ("TestModelBinder", "Home")) {
    <input type="text" name="items.tag[15-d]" value="Little Owl" />
    <input type="text" name="items.tag[19-a]" value="Merlin" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

If you have questions - add a comment and I will expand this answer.

Comment: sorry i have a question , if i am using a complex class and one of its properties is the `IList<AutoCompleteItem>` how can i bind that property with that model binder and the rest with the default model binder ?

Comment: You register the ModelBinder in Global.asx in Application_Start via: `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IList<AutoCompleteItem>), new AutoCompleteItemModelBinder ());`

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to name your fields key[0], value[0] (1,2,3 etc) and it should bind automatically since these are just strings. If you need to customize this for some reason - still name your fields key[0] value[0] (then 1,2,3 etc) and do exactly as specified here:
[ASP.NET MVC - Custom model binder able to process arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350689/asp-net-mvc-custom-model-binder-able-to-process-arrays)

Comment: i know but the i am not in control of the key it is not in sequence like 0 ,1 ,2 its 14-d , 19-a ,etc

Comment: ok.. then you need the other link I posted and your logic has to be built into the model binder to look for tag* items to parse out.