# MVC viewmodel array not being populated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have an action which takes a viewmodel.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SearchAjax(JQueryDataTablesModel jQueryDataTablesModel, BloodSearchAjaxViewModel searchModel)
{
...
```

In that viewmodel there is an array

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<string> mDataProp_ { get; set; }
```

When I call the action I verify via fiddler that the array data is being passed

[image]

However, the array (as well as other arrays in the viewmodel) are null.

Also, if I put in the viewmodel a field called`mDataProp_0` it gets populated.

Updated based on comment. Here is the code from the view where the data is posted. I'm using a jQueryDataTable. I didn't think this code mattered since I verified that the data is in the http request.

```
/* Initialize table */
        var oTable = $('#search-results-table').dataTableWithFilter({
                "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": 'SearchAjax',
                "sServerMethod": "POST",
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "mDataProp": "BloodIdentificationNumber" },
                    { "mDataProp": "Status" },
                    { "mDataProp": "ExpirationDate" },
                    { "mDataProp": "CompanyName" },
                    { "mDataProp": "Location" },
                    { "mDataProp": "City" }
                ],
                // Initialize our custom filtering buttons and the container that the inputs live in
                filterOptions: { searchButton: "search-button", clearSearchButton: "clear-search-button", searchContainer: "search-block" }
        });
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling the method using ajax/jQuery? Can you post the relevant code from the view?

Comment: Can you provide the full ajax request with all the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default model binder is pretty picky.  I think what you're seeing here is simply that the data isn't conforming to the conventions the binder expects.  Your options are either 1) massage the data to what the default binder accepts or 2) write a custom model binder.  Below are some links for both approaches.

[ASP.NET MVC - Custom model binder able to process arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350689/asp-net-mvc-custom-model-binder-able-to-process-arrays)
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: When I first read your answer I thought: "no, that's not it. The data is structured correctly, I've had MVC handle arrays for me several times in the past". But no, I was wrong :( I went back and read an old article and realized that you were right, and that the format of the data is indeed different that what I have seen (and what MVC handles out of the box). I wrote a custom model binder and all is well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Studying the project I saw that you must include a line in the Global.asax file.

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        // This line
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(JQueryDataTablesModel), new JQueryDataTablesModelBinder());
    }
```

Where JQueryDataTablesModel use as parameter the line below should be included in the Global.asax and the problem is solved.

Comment: Be aware that you are answering a question from a year ago, and that the requester has already set an approved answer. Better to reply to newer and unapproved questions.