# Can not parse datatable ajax request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, datatable, controller

I'm currently try to use the JQuery Datatables in my Project. This seem to work quite well, but I have problems to process the Ajax request for removing a row.

The Ajax request that is send by the datatables Editor plugin is formatted like:

> action=remove&table=pzeIpMaster&id=&data%5B%5D=3

The method in the controller looks like

```
[Authorize, HttpPost]
public ActionResult OnDeletePzeMaster(
  string action, string table, string id, string[] data)
```

The values of the parameters are

- action = remove
- table = pzeIpMaster
- id = ""
- **data = null**

Why is data set to null ?!! In my opinion data must be set to {3}

Thx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data%5B%5D decodes to data[]. So MVC can't match data[] with yor data parameter.

You could try this:

```
[Authorize, HttpPost]
public ActionResult OnDeletePzeMaster(
  string action, string table, string id)
{
var data = this.Request.Form["data[]"];
}
```

Or you could write a ModelBinder like this

[ASP.NET MVC - Custom model binder able to process arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350689/asp-net-mvc-custom-model-binder-able-to-process-arrays)

Comment: but that's the way the DataTables Editor is sending it? What would be the correct way to map it?

Comment: @BitKFu Maybe you can do something with this : editor.datatables.net/options/#ajaxUrl