# Pass querystring parameter + list of ids as POST to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm attempting to pass an id (long) plus a list of ids (array) to a controller action. The best luck I've had is getting the id to pass, but I've never gotten the array to post.

I've gone through at least 10 stack overflow articles today trying to get this to work. I'm sure I'm missing something minor, but I'm not sure what.

Javascript & AJAX:

```
        HandleCardReordering: function () {
            var ids = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < $(".CourseSectionId").length; i++) {
                ids[i] = $(".CourseSectionId:eq(" + i + ")").val();
            }
            var courseId = $("#CourseId").val();
            
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Content/CourseContent/ReorderCourseSections?courseId=" + courseId + "&sectionIds=" + JSON.stringify(ids),
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    //
                }
            });
        },
```

The ids collection and courseId are valid, I checked them with console.log and they look good.

My Controller method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> ReorderCourseSections(long courseId, [FromQuery]long[] sectionIds, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Json(new { success = "true" });
        }
```

I can get courseId to populate via the query string parameter, but sectionIds is always a length 0 array. I tried adding traditional: true, tried to stringify my ids collection, I added [FromQuery] to my sectionIds parameter. None worked. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Your parameter names and *types* need to match.  You're passing `sectionIds` as a *string* - MVC doesn't know you want that automatically parsed and the *default model binder* doesn't know how to convert it for you.  You have options 1) add a model binder that converts the json to a int array 2) change your parameter to a string (do this in the first instance) and parse it yourself in the action 3) change the format of how you pass your sectionIds (ie not as a JSON string)

Comment: I ended up using your #2 suggestion, and that works. If you can post your comment in the form of an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: That's just the first-pass to get it working.  See [this article](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).   And [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350689/asp-net-mvc-custom-model-binder-able-to-process-arrays) on how to add a custom model binder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possible solution:**

**1. First Approach:**

1- Change Parameter type from long[] to string.
2- You will get a string now parse it and convert it into long[] in controller.

```
public ActionResult Multiple(string sectionIds){
  long[] idsArray = sectionIds.Split(',').Select(long.Parse).ToArray();
  
}
```

**Second Approach:**

1- Change your queryparamter something like below example

```
?sectionIds=24041&sectionIds=24117
```

No need to change in controller . In .Netcore it will work.

```
http://localhost:5434/MukeshNProject/MultipleIds?ids=24041&ids=24117
public ActionResult MultipleIds([FromQuery] int[] ids)
{
}
```